# Accessing higher-level class from nested class in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have two Python classes, A and B, and that B is an attribute of A. Can a method of B modify a property of A? for example, I would like to be able to call

```
A.B.setXinA(1)
A.x
>>> 1
```

One way around it would be embed a reference to A in B:

```
A.B.reftoA = A
```

But that's rather ugly... Is there a way to access the higher-level class directly? Below is a working example using the second method:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, b):
    b.parent = self
    setattr(self, b.name, b)

class B:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

b = B('abc')
a = A(b)  # b is now a.abc
abc.parent.x = 1
a.x
>>> 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... If you have `a`, why not just write `a.x = 1` directly? And if you don't have `a` (suppose you're passed `b` without `a`), then I think it's best to be explicit and write `a = b.parent; a.x = 1` or `b.parent.x = 1` as you have written.

Comment: Yes the idea is that a is not directly accessible. It seems indeed that explicit is better, and it's fairly straightforwatd to do it.

Comment: There's no nested class in your code, they're both defined at the same "level".

Answer (score 0):

What about a method in B like this:

```
class B:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def setXinA(self, x):
      self.parent.x = x
```

Then:

```
>>> b = B('abc')
>>> a = A(b)

>>> b.setXinA(19)

>>> print(A.x)
19
```

This way requires that setXinA is called by an instance of B rather than just B.setXinA(42) for example. Also, it sets x as an attribue of the class A, rather than any particular instance of A.